# netcdf python error

Tags: arcpy, table, netcdf, ipython

I am basically copying and pasting the code provided on Esri's website and every time I try to run it in ipython, the program crashes and needs to restart the kernels.  The code is below, does anyone know what is happening?  Is there a known bug in the programming for this?

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set local variables
inNetCDFFile = "C:/Users/alex/Downloads/soilw.mon.mean.V2.nc"
variable = "soil"
outTableView = "fps_001"
rowDimension = "time"
dimensionValue = "[[lat{39.8736}],[lon{-104.3379}]]"
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFTableView
arcpy.MakeNetCDFTableView_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, outTableView, rowDimension, dimensionValue,valueSelectionMethod)
```

Comment: Try putting your lat and long is as strings rather than numbers

Comment: I like the suggestion; but if you mean simply add a ' to the outside of lat and lon to make 'lat' 'lon'.  I tried it, and I get an error.

Comment: No no. Check the tool. The numbers are actually taken as strings

Comment: Send me your email